# Wolfram Mathematica. 2 graphics in one plane

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I draw two functions with differrent limits of x in one plane?

For example, i have function f1(x) = x from 0 to 1 and f2(x) = x^2 from 1 to 2.

I need to have a picture of connected graphic.

Help, please...

Comment: `Show[ {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]}, PlotRange -> All]` (note you need to specify `PlotRange` else you just get the range of the first plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to draw them in the same interval like this?

```
f1[x_] := x;
f2[x_] := x^2;
Plot[{f1[c],f2[c+1]},{c,0,1}]
```